# Objective c parent and derived class have their own table view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am doing a proof of concept in `UIApplication` in xcode. In my application I have a common `tool bar` which include two buttons with action that shows the table view(list of items). I have done this programatically.

I have `10 viewcontroller` which require the tool bar with two buttons. how can I get the tool bar in all `viewcontroller` screen. some `viewcontroller` also have their own `table view`.

I just inherit the toolbar class to all `viewcontroller` . it works fine except some `viewcontroller` page which have their own `tableview`. because the parent class (toolbar class) and derived class both are having the `table view delegate` so the derived class `table view` is override when accessing the base class `table view`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make the toolbar as global, that is add it to the window instead of the view. This would then let it be viewed on all the `viewControllers`.

For this you would have to make an object of the `appDelegate` class and then declare it in the class in which you want to show your toolbar.

Something like ,

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate;  
appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

[appDelegate.window addSubview:Toolbar];
```

Any methods you would add would be working on all the `viewControllers` if they have been declared in a specific `viewController`